# Gitlab: application.js is taking too much time

Tags: gitlab

I have installed gitlab_7.7.2-omnibus.5.4.2.ci-1_amd64.deb and one file is taking too much time to respond and when I hit [ESC] on browser all page appears instantly

This is the file:

`http://localhost:8080/assets/application-5f3c67da81199dd3da676a30746cf17f.js`

Note: I disabled nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Apache, set **DocumentRoot** value in VirtualHost to `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public`.